# NPM packages version does not allow to update

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, next.js

I'm planning to build a Next.JS app using `create-next-app` however, I noticed at the package.json it results into

```
"eslint": "8.43.0",     
"eslint-config-next": "13.4.7",     
"next": "13.4.7",     
"react": "18.2.0",     
"react-dom": "18.2.0"
```

All of the packages do not have a tilde (`~`) nor caret (`^`) which will not allow me to update these packages in the future.

Some of my previous projects has tilde or caret in them.

Why is this happening? Should I manually put caret or tilde there? How can I be able to let npm automatically put caret or tilde? Am I missing something?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 4):

According to the Next.js documentation, this is intentional and recommended:

> We strongly recommend using exact versions in your package.json. This
> reduces the chance of different behavior between local development and
> production environments.

If you want to update your dependencies to newer versions, you can use the next update command, which will check for updates and install them safely. This command will also update your package.json file with the exact versions of the updated dependencies.

Comment: You can update next.js.